# Looking for a space movie with an alien artifact bomb

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, spaceship

The movie is from the 80s or 90s. (No it is not supernova).
What I remember of the plot is that it's set in the future where a spaceship encounters another spaceship (if it was that the spaceship had been missing for a while in space, and they happened to find it or if they responded to a distress call, I do not remember)

But on board the other ship, there is an alien artifact that they had found, which later turns out to be a bomb that an alien race have created to destroy all other civilisations that who have mastered space technology. What I remember was that the bomb would explode if it came to earth and wipe out everything.

Does anyone remember the name of the movie?

Comment: Are you definitely sure it's not Supernova (2000)? because your description is identical.

Answer (score 5):

At first I thought you were talking about an Outer Limits episode....
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_%28The_Outer_Limits%29

But I think you're referring to an episode of Babylon 5 called "[A Day in the Strife](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0517615/)" in which the Babylon 5 crew encounter a [Beserker Probe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_probe#Berserkers) which claims to be a peaceful ship of exploration.

Comment: Please explain what about the episode(s) matches the description in the question.

Comment: @phantom42 - I've edited. It certainly seems to match the description

Answer (score -2):

This is [Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_%28film%29) by Michael Crichton. Originally a novel, the movie starred Dustin Hoffman and Samuel Jackson, I believe.

The spaceship has been buried for 500 years in the deep ocean. It's from the future, but American. In one of its bays is an alien device that allows people to warp reality, and when humans have the ability they seem to wipe themselves out.

Comment: It sounds nothing like Sphere. The movie was released in the late 90's and is heavy on underwater scenes, so confusing it for outerspace is unlikely. Likewise, the only explosives are taken on board by the discoverers, not left behind in the salvaged vessel.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Don't be an ass. Story ident questions often have the year wrong. People remember a few key scenes. The whole point of the device is that it's a weapon of mass destruction. I'd accept this criticism by the person who asked, but not someone who has no idea whether or not it's the right answer.

Answer (score -3):

Supernova (2000 film)

Supernova chronicles the search and rescue patrol of a medical ship in deep space in the early 22nd century and its six-member crew which includes a Captain and Pilot, a co-pilot, a medical officer, a medical technician, a search and rescue paramedic, and a computer technician. When their vessel, the Nightingale 229, answers an emergency distress signal from a comet mining operation in a distant galaxy, the crew soon finds itself in danger from the mysterious young man they rescue, the alien artifact he's smuggled aboard, and the gravitational pull of a giant star about to supernova. The resulting explosion will be the most massive explosion in the universe.

Comment: Since the OP said (in the **second sentence**) "No it is not Supernova" it's safe to assume no. It's not Supernova. I'm not sure how you read the question without reading the question. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here.

Comment: Sure he said it's not Supernova, but there are a lot of movies called Supernova (I have seen two), and OP was not specific. Also if you have ever watched the above version of Supernova (or read the summary on Wikipedia even) you have to admit the description sounds darn near identical.